How can we share the JMeter html reports (index.html) to someone after generating through command line?
When I try sharing the report as an attachment through email it was opening as a text document. I have tried generating the link and kept that as "public" still not working. I was not confirmed if it can be done through SMTP sampler.
Any help or information will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.


The single index.html file won't contain all the information, you will need to send the whole folder containing folders content, sbadmin2-1.0.7 and files index.html and statistics.json. Basically it will be report-template folder but enriched with your current test results

You will need to put all these files and folder into an archive with OS Process Sampler or JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language prior to sending the file with SMTP Sampler
It needs to be done either in a separate .jmx script or you will need to add a tearDown Thread Group and trigger dashboard generation programmatically using JSR223 Sampler



Hi Ivan, I have tried the following steps:
Inside the TearDown thread group


Created the zip file Report350.zip and kept all the folders inside it which looks like a report-template and gave the file in the arguments of the OS Process Sampler.


Attached the file in SMTP sampler.


But getting the error for SMTP sampler as
Response code : 500
Response message : This message was blocked because its content presents a potential 552-5.7.0 security issue.
Please help.

Help you to send a message via email? Just protect the archive with a password so your shitty mail server wouldn't be able to unpack it and read the contents or report the issue to your mail provider. Also make sure to set jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflushJMeter Property  to true otherwise you can get incomplete results.

Thanks for the information Ivan. Actually, uploading the .rar archive file to drive worked simply for me without using samplers.

This should be a comment not an answer.

This should be a comment not an answer.
